# Is there a way to indent by the length of \phantom(text)?

Tags: captions, indentation, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs, phantom

I would like to write a text like this:

```
Text: This is a paragraph which is so long that it has a linebreak But the indent should be
      set after \phantom{Text: }.
```

How can I do that? How is it possible when writing normal text – and how can I do this with, for example, figure captions (with **variable** lengths (e.g, `Figure 1:` , …, `Figure 10:` , etc.))?

Comment: For captions using the caption package, use \captionsetup{format=hang}.  For normal text (single paragraph) use \hangindent=\widthof{...} (calc package).

Comment: And this solves my other problem. I would like to give you an upvote, but the new Firefox (combined with NoScript) does not allow me to do this. But I will give you an upvote as soon as I can.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Please describe how to use `\hangindent=\widthof{...}` properly. It does not seem to work. marmot’s solution, however, works.

Answer (score 2):

Note: `\caption` seems to like `\blindtext` better than `\lipsum`.  Also, `\hangindent` does not stop normal paragraph indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}

\newlength{\tempdima}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\hangindent}{\widthof{Test: }}
\noindent Test: \blindtext

\sbox0{Test: }%
\hangindent=\wd0
\noindent\box0\blindtext

\settowidth{\tempdima}{Test: }
\hangindent=\tempdima
\noindent Test: \blindtext

\begin{figure}[htp]
\captionsetup{format=hang}
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\widthof` is supported by package `calc`.  The support is added to the macros `\setlength`, `\addtolength`: `\setlength{\hangindent}{\widthof{Test: }}`. It does not work inside plain register assignments or eTeX's `\dimexpr`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek - Vielen Dank!  Have incorporated your solution.

Answer (score 1):

For normal text, I would use a description instead. If the vertical space above or the bold font of "Text" bother you, these can be changed.

[As also noted by John Kormylo:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403607/is-there-a-way-to-indent-by-the-length-of-phantomtext/403616#comment1005580_403607) To make a caption behave like this, the `caption` package offers a hanging format.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{description}
\item[Text] \lipsum[2] 
\end{description}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image} 
    \caption{long caption text that spans more than one line long caption text that spans more than one line long caption text that spans more than one line}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hanging` package, a LaTeX interface for the plain TeX `\hangindent=...\hangafter=...` construct.

The package defines a `\hangingpara`  command and a `hangingparas` environment. Demo:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\myhangindent}

\begin{document}

\settowidth{\myhangindent}{Text: }

\hangpara{\myhangindent}{1}%
Text: This is a paragraph which is so long that it has a linebreak at its end. But the indent
      should be set after \phantom(Text: ).

    \begin{hangparas}{\myhangindent}{1}%
\lipsum[10-12]
\end{hangparas}

\end{document}
```

[image]